# Best way to organize components in blade templates

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

lets say i have a blog with different posts and comments. Now I want to display the posts on different pages of my website. In most of the tutorials they to something like this:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <div class="post">
      <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
      [...]
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This seems fine, when you only have one page, where you want to display the post. But what if you have multiple pages with the same componente? Sure, you can use blades @component function. But how is the performance with this methods?

Let's say I have multiple sections where I want to display a post. And maybe my posts I multiple view variants. Would something like that be ok?

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    @component("section")
       @foreach ($posts as $post)
           @component("post", ["post" => $post])@endcomponent
       @endforeach
    @endcomponent

    @component("section")
       @foreach ($posts as $post)
           @component("post[highlight]", ["post" => $post])@endcomponent
       @endforeach
    @endcomponent
@endsection
```

**section.blade.php**

```
<section>{{ $slot }}</section>
```

**post.blade.php**

```
<div class="post {{css}}">
    <h2>{{$post->title}}</h2>
    [...]
</div>
```

**post[highlight].blade.php**

```
@component("post", ["post" => $post, "css" => "highlight"])@endcomponent
```

This would reduce dependencies and the templates would be clean. But it seems to me that this is not the usual way to organize blade templates.

Comment: Performance really shouldn't be much of a concern.  Laravel templates are compiled to PHP and cached, then PHP opcache will handle the rest when loading this repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do the loop in the `section.blade.php` and you can repeatedly access the post list every time you use

```
@component('section')
...
@endcomponent
```

If you want to load different lists at different layouts using the component, the best way to use is the `@slot()` as:

```
@slot('post')
...
@endslot
```

Now the slot expects a `$post` variable inside the component blade file (i.e. `section.blade.php`). You should manage to return a `$post` variable out of the loop.

Maybe this will help about [components and slots](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#components-and-slots)